# Display $query->result();

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap, foreach-loop-container

I'm having some trouble displaying the results of my query using a foreach loop in codeigniter. Heres my controller:

```
function viewall()
{
    $this->load->model('all');
    $data['query'] = $this->all->viewall();
    $this->load->view('all', $data);
}
```

Entire Model File:

```
<?php
class All extends CI_Model
{

function insert_into_db()
{
    $data = array('Error' => $this->input->post('f1'),
                  'Solution' => $this->input->post('f2')
                 );
    $this->db->insert('Errors', $data);
}

function viewall()
{
    $query = $this->db->select("Error, Solution")->from("Errors")->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

}

My view (where I think the problem is)

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Error</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Solution</h3></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($query->result_array() as $entry) ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry->Error; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->Solution;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Controller:

```
function viewall()
{
    $this->load->model('all');
    $data['results'] = $this->all->viewall();
    $this->load->view('all', $data);
}
```

#### Model:

```
function viewall()
{
    $query = $this->db->select("Error, Solution")->from("Errors")->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

#### View:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Error</h3></td>
            <td><h3>Solution</h3></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($results as $entry): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $entry->Error; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $entry->Solution;?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep `$query->result()`, as the OP accesses members like `$entry->Error` and not `$entry["Error"]`

Comment: Yes, I'd rather get it as an object

Comment: @JakeOls Already `object`. You dont need use `result_array` in foreach

Comment: Why is there a `:` after `foreach()`?

Comment: @JakeOls If you used `<?php foreach ($query as $entry): ?>` and not working, check results with `var_dump($query);`

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Im usign always with `:` ;)

Comment: I checked the results and got object(CI_DB_mysql_result)#16 (8) { ["conn_id"]=> resource(10) of type (mysql link persistent) ["result_id"]=> resource(14) of type (mysql result) ["result_array"]=> array(0) { } ["result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["custom_result_object"]=> array(0) { } ["current_row"]=> int(0) ["num_rows"]=> int(12) ["row_data"]=> NULL }

Comment: Depends on where you did the `var_dump($query);` of course. Try to `var_dump($query->result())` in the models `viewall()` function right before returning it.

Comment: @JakeOls @WouterHuysentruit right. Probably, this issue about `result()` or `result_array()`

Comment: @JakeOls can you please try your select like `'Error, Solution'`

Comment: Just did, still no luck.

Comment: @JakeOls You get error only this page? If you remove getting model, it works? You can define `define('ENVIRONMENT', 'development');` root `index.php` for debug.

Comment: Yes, the insert function on the page before works perfectly. It works if i remove the table from the view. the development environment is already definted in index.php

Comment: @JakeOls Can you paste whole model file to question. Probably this issue about your model file.

Comment: Could it have something to do with my libraries?

Comment: @JakeOls Just use in controller `function viewall()
{
    $this->load->view('all');
}` Works now?

Comment: @JakeOls can you use again updated view codes above please. I added to foreach `:` and `;`

Comment: IT FINALLY WORKED! :)

Comment: Thanks so much! I know this took foreverr!